# How to see which element of menu has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am working on a school project and we have to do a virtual static menu for a restaurant. What I've done until now is this: when I click on a button, a PopUp shows up and it's contained within the div with the class="menu". The thing is, that I stored all the menu items in a JSON file and thus I don't know how many items I'm going to have inside the menu. If you take a look at the code below, you can see that every menu item is contained within the < li > tag. Now, you can also see that the description start off with the display: none; property. What I am trying to do is this: Using Javascript(I don't think it's possible with plain HTML and CSS), how can I set the style of the description to display: block; of that particular item when either the "title" class or the "svg-container" class is called? In either case, when the svg or the title is pressed, the svg MUST rotate 90 degrees and return to 0 degrees when it's clicked again. The problem is that I don't know how to get the reference of the exact item that has been pressed so I can show it's description...

This is a visual representation of what the menu looks like for now:

[image]

And this is why I need the description to be set to display: block;

[image]

```
<div class="menu">
        <h2>Our Menu</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <div class="svg-container"> <img class="arrow" src="right-arrow.svg"/></div>
                    <span class="title">Fried Fish With Souce</span>
                    <div class="description" style="display: none;">
                            This is some internal content.This is some internal content.This is some internal content.
                    </div>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <div class="svg-container"> <img class="arrow" src="right-arrow.svg"/></div>
                    <span class="title">Spaghetti</span>
                    <div class="description" style="display: none;">
                            This is some internal content.This is some internal content.This is some internal content.
                    </div>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I tried my best to explain the problem in a clear way, for any questions or uncertainties I am here to answer. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
Thanks everyone for the quick help, but after implementing your code, there is a slight problem, look what happens when the title is too long to fit inside the menu div:

[image]

As you can see, the title moves completely on a new line, but what it should just move the content that doesn't fit(WITHOUT splitting the word, only if there is a space) on the new line.

Comment: In your event handlers for `title` and `svg-container`, you can find out exactly what element triggered the event by looking at the `event.target` and you could then access the styling of that element with `event.target.classList` and then use `.add()`, `.remove()`, `toggle()`, etc. Also, you are using `label` incorrectly. The `label` element is for connecting a caption with a form field, not for wrapping regular HTML content.

Comment: This is honestly a pretty interesting question

Comment: i see label within the code, so where are the inputs you could use to toggle display via css ? examples : https://jsfiddle.net/3gxr1Lys/ & https://jsfiddle.net/3gxr1Lys/1/ ... forgot about the arrow : https://jsfiddle.net/3gxr1Lys/2/

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is a creative technique I must say, I'll try and implement it. Also, thanks for the heads up about the label.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I just said that there is no way to do this without javascript, you just proved me wrong. Thanks for the quick response and putting the time to actually implement it. But there is a slight problem, I edited the post above, it would be helpful to solve it.

Comment: I explained why the text is on its own line in the "Other" section of my answer below. It has nothing to do with the length of the text, it's because you put that `span` outside of the `div` that holds the arrow instead of within that `div`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It makes sens, but the thing is that if I put the < /div > of the arrow(svg-container) after the < /span > of the title, this is what happens: https://imgur.com/1WuK57P . Probably because I resized the div of the svg-container... .svg-container { display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 1.8vw; overflow: hidden; }

Comment: not sure about your edit and text too long, is it supposed to wrap or be truncated showing ellipsis ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it is supposed to be wraped on a new line, only the words that don't fit inside the remaining width of the menu

Comment: I have addressed that issue 3 times for you. Once in these comments, once in my answer, and once in the comments below my answer. The reason you are getting that very narrow result isn't because the HTML is wrong, it's because your CSS styling is wrong.

Comment: oh i see , grid could easily help : https://jsfiddle.net/7pr1jcof/

Comment: @ScottMarcus your answer is doing the job and js makes sure it works everywhere . someone should upvote ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That fixed it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ScottMarcus I know that I'm kind of at the beginning stages of learning Web Development and I expect myself to do a lot of mistakes, I just like when people point out to me what I did wrong and how I can correct it and avoid that mistake in the future. You definitively helped a lot and I am working right now on your Javascript solution. Sorry if I've made you nervous but I couldn't connect the dots. Now I have to check where my CSS styling is wrong so it causes that narrow effect, I'll fix it somehow, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is handle the click at the `.menu` level and then determine exactly which item within the menu was clicked using `[event.target][1]`. This approach leverages event bubbling using a technique called "[event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)".

```js
// Set up event listener on the menu
document.querySelector(".menu").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // The actual item within the menu that was clicked is accessible 
  // through event.target. So, we'll find the nearest ancestor <li> 
  // of that, and then search for the .description element within that
  // and change the style
  event.target.closest("li").querySelector(".description").classList.remove("hidden");

});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
        <h2>Our Menu</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                    <div class="svg-container"> 
                      <img class="arrow" src="right-arrow.svg"/>
                      <span class="title">Fried Fish With Souce</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description hidden">
                            This is some internal content.This is some internal content.This is some internal content.
                    </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <div class="svg-container"> 
                      <img class="arrow" src="right-arrow.svg"/>
                      <span class="title">Spaghetti</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="description hidden">
                            This is some internal content.This is some internal content.This is some internal content.
                    </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Other:**

- You are not using the [`label` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) correctly. It is meant to
  associate a caption with a form field, not regular HTML elements.
- If you want the text of the menu item to be next to the arrow, you'll
  need that `span` to be inside of the previous `div`, not outside of
  it.
- Avoid inline styles when possible and use CSS classes instead.
- If you want to be able to toggle the visibility of a clicked item
  (show/hide/show/hide, etc.), use [`.classList.toggle` instead of `classList.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never knew that there is such a technique with Javascript. Obviously, I've got to learn a lot. I'll try to implement it right now. Is there any advantage to doing it with Javascript instead of CSS(see the solution that G-Cyrillus commented on the post above)? Also, sorry for the inconvenience but there is a problem right now, I Edited the post above, it would be very helpful to solve it.

Comment: @JasperHoward There's never just one way to solve a problem. G-Cyrillus' answer is perfectly good and removes the need for JavaScript, which makes the solution less code intensive. However, it requires a bit more knowledge of CSS and HTML form fields. Neither is better or worse than the other in this case. Also, with regard to your edit, as I've stated, I've addressed that in my Other section. It has nothing to do with the length of the words, it's your `span` tag in the wrong place. See my answer, which has it in the correct place.